# Angular custom library module not found after updating to version 15

Tags: node.js, angular, module, angular15

I have updated my custom library and UI Angular applications to version 15 but now when I try to run "ng serve" it says it can't find the module for my custom library.  We are working with Artifactory for our repositorys. And I noticed that since I updated the Jenkins build to use Node 16 it packages the npm package differently.

So I'm curious if anyone has come across this before.  I was able to consume the library without any issues when it was version 11, but after the update to 15 I get the following error.

> Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@cto_compliance_amf/amf-library' in 'C:\Users\zkafpf7\Documents\MyProjects\amf_ui\src\app'

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when I updated to Node 16 for the Jenkins build, the babel script wasn't working correctly.  I updated my pre-pack script to use shx instead of babel to move the files from the dist folder to the root folder. Then updated the .npmignore file to omit the files that weren't needed in the package. And now everything works. Hope this helps someone else.